# Back button not reappearing on iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode

I've created an if statement that will hide the back button when the table is editing.

But when leaving editing mode I can't get the back button to reappear.

```
    - (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated 
    {
    NSLog(@"Edit");
    bool e = [tableView isEditing];
    e=!e;
    [tableView setEditing:e animated:YES];
    [super setEditing:e animated:YES];

    if (editing)
    {
    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:NO];
        UIBarButtonItem *add = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(pushViewController:animated:)];
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = add;
    }
    else if (editing == false)
    {
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem;
    //[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:NO animated:NO];
    }
}
```

I've added an NSLog to the else statement and it appears that it's not being called at all.

EDIT: I solved it, I simple replaced if(editing == true) with if(e == true) it now works, thanks for all the help though.

Comment: Please change value of bool variable "editing" while click on button i think your code is perfect..å

Comment: Could you be more specific please?

Comment: I mean you have taken boolean variable editing in .h file right?
so change value of yes and no alternatively while click on button

Comment: bool e = [tableView isEditing];
declare e globally i mean in .h file

Answer (score 0):

you need to set editing == false, or remove the else if and replace it with else.
Currently you are testing twice for editing == true

```
if (editing){
    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:NO];
    UIBarButtonItem *add = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(pushViewController:animated:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = add;
}else{
    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:NO animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: check Mathew Vargheses Answer for restoring the backbutton

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the leftbar button to default backbutton as follows.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem   =   self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem;
```

**EDIT**: Can you please try like this?

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated 
{
    NSLog(@"Edit");
    bool e = [tableView isEditing];
    e=!e;
   [tableView setEditing:e animated:YES];
   [super setEditing:e animated:YES];

    if (editing)
    {
        UIBarButtonItem *add = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(pushViewController:animated:)];
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = add;
    } 
    else
    {
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem;
    }
}
```

Try this. Glad if this helps you in anyway. :)

Comment: I've corrected my if/else statement to (editing == false) and still no luck with this method

Answer (score 0):

edit:
I just tried the following code in a project and it works as intended, hiding and reappearing the backButton:

```
- (IBAction)testButton:(id)sender {
    hide = !hide;
    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:hide animated:NO];
}
```

hide starts with NO. Every time I press the testButton the back appears or disappears.

Are you making any modifications to the navigationController or the navigationItem while the backButton is hidden?

Comment: Try [self.navigationItem setNeedsDisplay]; after you setHidden:NO.

Comment: I'm not using interface builder, i'm doing this all programmatically

Comment: Are you modifying navigationController or navigationItem while the back button is hidden? Make the same test as I did, create a button and make it call a method just like the one I posted and create the variable BOOL hiden in the interface. You dont need Inteface Builder to do that. It should make the button appear and disappear.